# XPath Find items

Tags: xml, xpath

How can I return all the 'make' items from the xml document using an xpath query

```
<vehicles>
<car>
    <make>Benz</make>
    <make>Nissan</make>
</car>
<motorbike>
    <make>Honda</make>
</motorbike>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `/*/*/make`. (You could use `//make`, but I try to avoid `//` for efficiency reasons.)

The w3schools has a good tutorial on XPath: [http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_intro.asp)

Also, you should add `</vehicles>` to your XML to make it well formed.

Comment: Oops... forgot to add the ending tag.. .Cheers